# undefined local variable or method "articles_path"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm trying to complete this tutorial : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#say-hello-rails but i'm getting an error with this:

```
<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>
```

I have next error:

```
undefined local variable or method `articles_path' for #<#<Class:0x4646c28>:0x4661d30>
Extracted source (around line #1):
```

`rake routes`:

```
Prefix Verb URI Pattern                      Controller#Action
welcome_index GET /welcome/index(.:format)   welcome#index
 articles_new GET /articles/new(.:format)    articles#new
         root GET /                          welcome#index`
```

`ArcticlesController`:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
  end
end
```

Help please!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess you forgot to add `resources :articles` in your `config/routes.rb` file. As it done in guide:

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :articles

  root 'welcome#index'
end
```